# What is the symbol/s for spacebar press when using the `screen stuff` command?

Tags: bash, symbols, gnu-screen, keystroke, stuff

I have a screen command as such..

`screen -S sessionname -X stuff 'spacebar'`

I want to replace "spacebar" with the appropriate symbol/s to emulate a spacebar press.  I would also like to know what the symbol/s are for the arrows to.  I couldn't find a reference after multiple searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol for the spacebar is a space:

```
screen -S sessionname -X stuff ' '
```

Comment: hmm.. can't believe I didn't try that.